# Differences between using dissimilarity matrix and data matrix as input in clustering in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-structures, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm just struggling about the input data structure when using clustering.

Let's say I have dataframe like this and all variables are continuous variables, then I want to implement k-means/k-medoids on that.

```
df <- data.frame(age = c("20", "50", "35", "45"), 
                 height = c("160", "178", "152", "169"), 
                 weight = c("50", "80", "65", "57"))
```

In my mind, there are two ways to implement clustering but I'm not sure which one has better performance, or are they just equivalent?

1. scale the df and doing k-means directly.
2. calculating the dissimilarity matrix first then doing k-means.

I know that if my data contains categorical variables, I can utilize Gower's distance to calculate the dissimilarity matrix first and do clustering, but I'm not sure that is it a better way to do clustering when my data doesn't include any categorical variables?